# Getting Details of all Dependent contacts of a particular Contact

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am using an SOQL query like this

```
SELECT Id,Name from Contact where FisrtName = 'ABC' and LastName ='DEF'
```

And it is working fine. Now I want to retrieve all the dependent Contacts of this particular Contact by modifying this same SOQL query. How can I do this. 
Please help me out of this

Comment: What do you mean by dependent contacts? Do you mean all contacts that belong to the same account?

Comment: @GarethJordan No. For a dependent contact ReportstoId field value will be the Id of parent contact.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the describe details of the Contact Object the relationship for the Reports To field is null, so it looks like you cant do the subquery on that.

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dsr = Contact.sObjectType.getDescribe();
List<Schema.ChildRelationship> crs = dsr.getChildRelationships();
for(Schema.ChildRelationship cr : crs){
    System.debug('Field = '+ cr.getField() + ' '+cr.getChildSObject() +' '+ cr.getRelationshipName());
}
```

You would most likely need to just run a second query like this:

```
List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id,Name from Contact where FisrtName = 'ABC' and LastName ='DEF'];
List<Contact> relatedContacts = [SELECT Id,Name from Contact where ReportsToId IN :contacts];
```

Comment: Thanks. I already got answer in this way. I just want to know whether i can get the result in single SOQL

Comment: Whenever you need to check that just describe the object and check the relationships, I could have just said no but wanted to show why for future reference.